# Call Oracle procedure in Java code

Tags: java

I tried to call this procedure in Java code:

```
create or replace procedure statistics_function
    ( namein                        in varchar2
    , lob_out                       out nocopy clob )
is
    cursor last_60_cpu_cursor       is
        select 1 as last_60_cpu, sysdate as last_60_event_date
        from dual
    ;
begin
    dbms_lob.createtemporary(lob_loc => lob_out, cache => true, dur => dbms_lob.session);

    for cv in last_60_cpu_cursor loop
        dbms_lob.append(lob_out, to_char(cv.last_60_event_date)||'i'||to_char(cv.last_60_cpu)||chr(10));
    end loop;

    dbms_lob.append(lob_out, 'last_60_cpu'||chr(10)||chr(10));
end statistics_function;
```

Java code:

```
public static void main(String Args[]) throws SQLException
{
    DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@31.187.70.163:1521:xe", "admin", "qwerty");

    CallableStatement cstmt = conn.prepareCall("statistics_function(?, ?); end;");

    cstmt.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);
    cstmt.setString(1, "agent");

    cstmt.execute();
    String result = cstmt.getString(1);
    conn.close();
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
```

Can you help me to fix this problem. I suppose that I have some mistake in Java code?

Can you propose some solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong :
Try this:

`CallableStatement cstmt = conn.prepareCall("{ call statistics_function(?, ?)}");`